# jquery - each / click function not working

Tags: jquery, click, each

**EDIT: this works, but not sure why?**

```
  $('button').each(function() {
    $(this).bind(
        "click",
        function() {
            alert($(this).val());
        });
  });
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working... Right now, I'm just trying to output an alert with the button value, but it's not working on my page.  I don't get any console errors in Firebug and can't see anything that would prevent it from working.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<table id="addressbooktable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>7892870</td>
        <td><button id="button-20" class="custom-action" value="XY89" name="info">Click</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>9382098</td>
        <td><button id="button-21" class="custom-action" value="XY544" name="info">Click</button></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>3493900</td>
        <td><button id="button-22" class="custom-action" value="XY231" name="info">Click</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And the code looks like this:

```
  $('button').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      alert($(this).val());
    }
  });
```

But, clicking on it does nothing at all?  Am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: Probably not the problem, but you don't need the .each, you can use .click on a jQuery object with more than one node and it will bind them all.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can bind all buttons with a click event like this, there is no need to loop through them

```
$(function(){
    $("button").click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr("value"));
    });
});
```

But a more precise selector might be:

```
$(function(){
    $("button[id^='button-'").click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr("value"));
    });
});
```

Comment: This is much more efficient, since the selector already holds reference to the elements, rather than treating each() element as a separate item.

Answer (score 7):

You're missing a `);`, and make sure your code is in a `document.ready` handler, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('button').each(function() {
    $(this).click(function() {
      alert($(this).val());
    }); //missing ); here!
  });
});
```

This way it won't run until those `<button>` elements are in the DOM for `$('button')` to find them.  Also, you can run [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) on a set of elements, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
      alert($(this).val());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `)`:

```
$('button').each(function(){
            $(this).click(function(){
                alert($(this).val());
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup. Try this:

```
$('button').click(function() {
      alert($(this).val());
  });
```

You may also want a `return false` or `.preventDefault()` in there.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `.val()` method for button. You can use [**`.attr()`**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to get the value attribute. If you are using custom attributes then use [**data-attribute**](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/).

Try

```
$("button").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr("value"));
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the responses... After posting, I used "bind" and it seems to work...  Wondering if someone can explain why it works in this case, but not in the original?  I'm editing my post to show what I changed it to...

Comment: @N00BNum1 - you ere missing a `);` in your code, so it wasn't valid...see my answer :)